# How can I get a delegate method in ViewController to see when *recorder is finished (different class)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, avaudiorecorder

I have a singleton

```
@implementation RDTRecord
@synthesize recorder;
+(RDTRecord *)sharedRecorder
{
static RDTRecord* sharedRecorder;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedRecorder = [[RDTRecord alloc]init];
});
return sharedRecorder
}
```

and a method:

```
- (void)doRecordAudio:(int)increment{
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
... file location etc.
 recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:settings               error:&error];
if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];

    [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 3.0]
}
```

in a class `RDTRecord`

I call this from a "record" button in `RDTViewController` using the following:

```
-(IBAction)recordButton:(UIButton *)sender

        //somenumber is not initialized yet so plug any int in here
        [[RDTRecord sharedRecorder] doRecordAudio:somenumber]; 
}
```

I want to implement the delegate...

```
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)sharedRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag {
...do some stuff here
}
```

in my `RDTViewController` *not* in `RDTRecord`

the interface for my vc is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RDTRecord.h"

@interface RDTViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;

- (IBAction)recordButton:(UIButton *)sender;
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)sharedRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

.h for `RDTRecord` is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "RDTViewController.h"

@interface RDTRecord : NSObject {
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) AVAudioRecorder *recorder;

+(RDTRecord *)sharedRecorder;
- (void)doRecordAudio:(int)increment;
@end
```

The question is: How can I get the delegate method `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` in my `RDTViewController` to "see" when the `*recorder` is finished if the `*recorder` is in class `RDTRecord`? 
Or perhaps another way to ask the same question would be: how do I let the AVAudioRecorder *recorder object "know" to use the delegate if the delegate is in another class - such as `RDTViewController` and what would that code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `RDTRecord` the delegate of the audio recorder and have it implement `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:`. But, also give it a property `@property (assign) id <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> delegate;` and, when your view controller wants to trigger a recording have it set itself as the delegate of `RDTRecord`.

Now, when `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` is called in `RDTRecord` it can forward the callback to its delegate:

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)sharedRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.delegate audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:sharedRecorder successfully:flag];
}
```

(you could also add the delegate as a parameter of `doRecordAudio:`, and `nil` the `delegate` after the callback has run depending on your other requirements).

The view controller should remove itself as a delegate when it is done (and before it is destroyed).

Comment: I'm with you up to "when your view controller wants to trigger a recording have it set itself as the delegate of `RDTRecord.`" Would i do this in `RDTViewController` like `RDTRecord.delegate=self;` or `[RDTRecord setDelegate: self];` Neither of those are working in VC because there is no `delegate` property (that's in RDTRecord`) and no known class method for setDelegate in VC

Comment: That's because you are trying to call the class, not the instance: `[RDTRecord sharedRecorder].delegate = self`

Comment: You are the man! I've been going round and round with this for quite some time - appears to working quite well! Thank you

Comment: Just for reference: I made both `RDTRecord` and `RDTViewController` `<AVAudioRecorderDelegate>`'s that implement `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording. I also added `recorder.delegate = self;` in `RDTRecord` - making RDTRecord the delegate of `AVAudioRecorder *recorder` So then it triggers delegate method in `RDTRecord` which calls `[self.delegate audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:sharedRecorder successfully:flag];`